Url Automatically Hitting
`I've created /register API and sending the URL for email verification to Welcome.vm file on mail.
But the url sent on mail is being hit automatically without even clicking on "Verify Email" button.
I am attaching the code of my both APIs
/register
/successfullyVerify
And also I am attaching the template file
welcome.vm
THIS IS /register API.
@PostMapping("/register")
    public String register(@RequestBody SignUpRequest signUpReq, HttpServletRequest request) {
        String result = "";
        ProcessException pe = null;
        validator = new CommonValidator();
        List<FieldError> errorList = new ArrayList<>();
        // commented for now
        SignUpResponse signUpResponse = null;
        Response<SignUpResponse> apiResponse = new Response<>();
        try {
            isValidSignUpRequest(signUpReq, errorList);
            if (errorList.size() == 0) {
                isDuplicateCustomer(signUpReq, errorList);
                if (errorList.size() == 0) {
                    CustomerDTO customerDto = customerService
                            .saveOrUpdateCustomer(new SignUpRequest().convertToCustomerDTO(signUpReq));
                    if (customerDto != null && customerDto.getAccountDTO() != null) {
                        SettingDTO setting = settingService.getSettingByCode(SettingStatus.RESET_PWD_URL.getCode());
                        String templateFileName = CommonConstant.WELCOME_TEMPLATE_NAME_CUSOTOMER;
                        String subject = CommonConstant.WELCOME_EMAIL_SUBJECT_CUSOTOMER;
                        InternetAddress toEmail = new InternetAddress();
                        toEmail.setAddress(customerDto.getAccountDTO().getEmail());
                        Map<String, Object> objectValueMap = new HashMap<>();
                        objectValueMap.put("name", customerDto.getName());

                        objectValueMap.put("verificationUrlPlaceholder", "${verificationUrl}");

                        if (setting != null) {

                            String verificationUrl = setting.getName() + "successfullyverify.html?customerId="
                                    + customerDto.getCustomerId();
                            objectValueMap.put("verificationUrl", verificationUrl);
                        }
                        objectValueMap.put("mail", customerDto.getAccountDTO().getEmail());
                        mailService.sendMail(new InternetAddress[] { toEmail }, null, subject, objectValueMap,
                                templateFileName, null, null, null);

                        apiResponse.setResponseMessage("Registration is successful. Please verify your email.");
                    } else {
                        apiResponse.setResponseCode(String.valueOf(ApiResponseStatus.FAIL.getCode()));
                        apiResponse.setResponseMessage(ApiResponseStatus.FAIL.getDesc());
                    }

                } else {
                    pe = new ProcessException(ErrorType.MULTIPLE_ERROR);
                    pe.setFieldErrorList(errorList);
                }

            } else {
                pe = new ProcessException(ErrorType.MULTIPLE_ERROR);
                pe.setFieldErrorList(errorList);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("saved customer error in catch => " + e.getMessage(), e);
            e.printStackTrace();
            pe = new ProcessException(ErrorType.GENERAL);
            pe.setFieldErrorList(errorList);
        }
        // commented for now
        // apiResponse.setData(signUpResponse);
        result = APIUtil.formatJsonResponse(apiResponse, pe);
        logger.info("customerSignUp() => finish");
        return result;
    }

THIS IS /successfullyVerify
@GetMapping(value = "/successfullyverify")
    public String getSuccessfullyVerify(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestParam(name = "customerId") Long customerId,
            Model model) {
        String userAgent = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
        if (userAgent != null
                && (userAgent.contains("Mozilla") || userAgent.contains("Chrome") || userAgent.contains("Safari"))) {

            System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>+++++" + userAgent);
            CustomerDTO customerDTO = customerService.findById(customerId);
            if (CommonUtil.validLong(customerId)) {

                // if (CommonUtil.validInteger(customerDTO.getEmailVerify())) {
                if (customerDTO.getEmailVerify() == 1) {
                    return "verificationFailed";
                } else {
                    customerService.updateEmailVerifyById(customerId);
                    SettingDTO setting = settingService
                            .getSettingByCode(SettingStatus.CUSTOMER_LOGIN_PORTAL_URL.getCode());
                    if (setting != null && CommonUtil.validString(setting.getName())) {
                        model.addAttribute("loginUrl", setting.getName());
                    }

                    String templateFileName = CommonConstant.CONFIRMATION_TEMPLATE_NAME_CUSOTOMER;
                    String subject = CommonConstant.CONFIRMATION_EMAIL_SUBJECT_CUSOTOMER;
                    InternetAddress toEmail = new InternetAddress();
                    toEmail.setAddress(customerDTO.getAccountDTO().getEmail());
                    Map<String, Object> objectValueMap = new HashMap<>();
                    objectValueMap.put("name", customerDTO.getName());

                    objectValueMap.put("url", "https://www.knightfrank.com/");

                    objectValueMap.put("mail", customerDTO.getAccountDTO().getEmail());
                    mailService.sendMail(new InternetAddress[] { toEmail }, null, subject, objectValueMap,
                            templateFileName, null, null, null);
                }

            }

            return "successfullyverify";
        }

        return "successfullyverify";
    }

THIS IS Template file
<html>
  <head> </head>
  <body>
    <p>Dear ${name},</p>
    <p>
      You are on the final step to activating your Knight Frank Auction App
      account.
    </p>
    <p>Click "Verify Email" to activate your account.</p>
    <br />
    
    <a
      href="${verificationUrl}"
      style="
        font-size: 13px;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        border-radius: 0.25rem;
        font-size: 14px;
        margin-bottom: 5px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        text-decoration:none;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #c00000;
        border-color: #c00000;
      "
      >Verify Email</a
    ><br /><br />
    <p>
      Regards<br />
      The Knight Frank Auction Team <br />
    </p>
    <p style="color: #7f7f7f">
      <i>This is an automated email, please do not reply</i>
    </p>
  </body>
  <html> 

